# How can I create new language layout in Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I need a tutorial tour about creating a new language layout with a different name for Ubuntu, downloadable for all and which everyone can install them on their Ubuntu OS.

I was searched on internet for this tutorial and I found 2 tutorials, but those are not clear and not for beginners.

Comment: Please rephrasing your question to point out what you don't understand in each of the tutorials.

Comment: i want to enter a new charecter and delete the unwanted charecter,and i coud be install this keyboard layout in other Pc with offline mode

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a new keyboard layout (Custom keyboard layout definition)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/482678/how-to-add-a-new-keyboard-layout-custom-keyboard-layout-definition) or [What are the steps needed to create new keyboard layout on ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510024/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-create-new-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu?lq=1)